# Android Integration Test: How to mock ClipData of intent of the onActivityResult using the Expresso intent

Tags: android, android-intent, integration-testing

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin. I am writing Integration Tests for my application using the Expresso framework. Now, I am struggling to mock the ClipData of the intent of the onActivityResult callback. I am mocking the intent using the expresso-intent of the Expresso framework.

Following is the implementation of my onActivityResult callback method.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.i(TAG, "Start handleGalleryActivityResult")
        if (data?.clipData?.itemCount == null) {
            return
        }

        if (data?.clipData?.itemCount as Int > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "handleGalleryActivityResult: clipData count is greater than zero")
            for (i in 0 until data?.clipData?.itemCount as Int) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing index ${i}")
                if (data?.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri != null) {
                    val file: File = File(data?.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri?.path)
                    Log.i(TAG, "Picked gallery file ${data?.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri?.path}")
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Picked gallery file at index ${i} is null")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the onActivityResult callback method, I am retrieving the clipData of the intent.

I am writing a test mocking the returned intent as follows.

```
@Test fun filesAreUploadedToServerWhenPickedUpFromGallery() {
        this.launchActivityWithIntent()
        val resultData = Intent()
        val result = Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData)
        intending(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK)).respondWith(result)
        onView(withId(R.id.camera_image_btn_gallery)).perform(click())

        //the rest of the code goes here
    }
```

As you can see in my code, I am mocking the intent to be returned like this.

```
intending(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK)).respondWith(result)
```

My question is how can I pass the Clip Data to the intent to mock it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `ClipData` object as

1. Create `ClipDescription` and `ClipData.Item` object

   ```
   val clipDescription = ClipDescription("Dummy", arrayOf(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN))

   val uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");

   val clipItem = ClipData.Item(uri)
   ```
2. Create `ClipData` object and set it on intent object as:

   ```
   val _clipData = ClipData(clipDescription, clipItem)

   resultData.clipData = _clipData
   ```

You can add more items using [addItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData#addItem(android.content.ClipData.Item)) as `_clipData.addItem(clipItem)`. You can use other constructors and method of [ClipDescription](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipDescription#public-constructors) and [ClipData.Item](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.Item#public-constructors) classes to add more data.

Alternately, You can create the actual mock objects and mock the corresponding methods for the same used objects, as per your mocking framework.